# Pushing onto nested subdoc array with MongooseJS

Tags: mongoose

I have the following schema in MongooseJS:

```
const ParentChildCommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  date: Date,
  from: { type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Parent' },
  message: String,
});

const ParentChildSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  child: { type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Child' },
  comments: [ ParentChildCommentSchema ],
});

const ParentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  description: String,
  children: [ ParentChildSchema ],
});
```

Where `Parents` have `Children`, and each Parent/Child relationship can have an array of `comments`.

I'm trying to push a `comment` with

```
const query = {
  "_id": parentId,
  "children._id": parentChildId,
};

const update = {
  "$push": { 
    "children.$.comments": { 
      "date": Date.now(),
      "from": parentId,
      "message": message,
    }
  }
};

Pack.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, err => ...)
```

The query isn't throwing any errors. But no comment is being added. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure if this will make much of a difference, but change `"$push"` to `$push`

Comment: I don't think that makes a difference. I have an almost identical query that $set's a value in the ParentChildSchema and it works fine wrapped in quotes.

Comment: Tested it, but no luck. Still completes successfully, but doesn't push onto the array.

Comment: why is there a `$` in this: `children.$.comments`?

Comment: Because `children` is itself an array. Using `children.$.comments` will target  the item in `children` specified in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was in the router -- not passing the ParentChild id through -- so the code above is correct and working properly.